# Make the column values static in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two columns in google sheets. 1st column `column A` is the input column and the second column `column B` is the output column. I want the values in the second column to be static once I enter the values in the 1st column. (as the results in the second column are based on the values entered in the first column)

Comment: What do you mean by static? If you change input then output will be changed.

Comment: I mean - any changes/entries made in column A should not change the already-generated values in column B

Comment: Then you need script (formula can't do it).

Comment: Sure. That will do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic script that takes the value to the right of the edited cell and makes it "static":

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var staticCell = e.range.offset(0,1); // Finds the cell to the right of the edited one
  var staticVal = staticCell.getValue(); // Gets the value of that cell

  staticCell.setValue(staticVal); // Sets the cell value to itself, removing the formula and making the cell "static"
}
```

Here is another script that does the same thing, but only works when column A is edited (specific to this question):

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var staticCell = e.range.offset(0,1);
  var staticVal = staticCell.getValue();

  if(e.range.columnStart == 1){ // Checks to see if the edited cell is in column A
    staticCell.setValue(staticVal);
  } else {}; // If it is not in column A, nothing happens
}
```